# Confusion about using bitwise operators in c

Tags: c

```
int example(int x) {
   // Example input: x = 0x89ABCDEF
   // In binary: 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111

   int a = x >> 24;    // 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 1001
   int a2 = a & 0xff;

   return a;
}
```

When I run my example code, I expect a = 137. Shifting x to the right by 24 bits should give
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 1001, which is 137 in decimal form. However, my program returns a = -119.

I made a modification in a2, which gave me the correct result. I don't really understand how a2 is any different from a, and why they output different values. Wouldn't using the & operator with 0xff return the same thing, making a = a2?

Comment: Because `x` is `int`, it is _signed_. So, you get an _arithmetic_ right shift [vs. a _logical_ right shift]. Arithmetic right shift does sign extension (i.e. when shifting in, it shifts in the _sign_ bit [bit 31]). Your original bit pattern has bit 31 _on_, so you'll get that shifted in. Try it with `unsigned int` instead of `int`. Logical right shift will shift in a 0 instead of the contents of bit 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `int` to an `unsigned int` to force the use of a logical shift as you expect.

---

Each shift effectively divides the number by 2. You started with -1,985,229,329, so you ended up with -1,985,229,329 / 2<sup>24</sup> = -119. This is the correct result, not 137.

Correctly dividing the number is achieved by changing what kind of shifting is performed based on whether it's a signed integer or an unsigned integer.

With unsigned integers, `>>` performs a [*logical shift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) right. A logical shift right will shift in a zero.

[image: Logical shift right]

With signed integers, `>>` performs an [*arithmetic shift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) right. An arithmetic shift right shifts in the sign bit.

[image: Arithmetic shift right]

You were expecting a logical shift, but got an arithmetic shift. You could get the desired shift by casting the `int` to an `unsigned int`. Better yet, use an `unsigned int` from the start.

---

Images courtesy of the linked Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 3):

You're performing a right shift on a signed integer.  Assuming 2's complement representation, the value in question is actually negative since the high-order bit is set.  Most 2's complement implementations will shift in "1" bits on left if the high bit is set to preserve the sign.

By performing a bitwise-AND with `0xff`, you're setting the upper bytes to all-bits-0.

If the type of `x` was `unsigned`, that would mean 0's are always shifted in from the left.

Answer (score 1):

For the *left shift* operation, every bit is replaced by the immediate right bit, except the 0-th bit. **The 0-th bit gets replaced by 0**.

For the *right shift* operation, every bit is replaced by the immediate left bit, except the last bit.

**For right shift of signed values, the sign bit remains constant**. If it were 1 before the shift began, it will remain 1 and if it were 0, before the shift began, it will remain 0.

**But for right shift of unsigned values, the last bit is replaced by 0**.

You passed `x = 0x89ABCDEF` as an `int`, i.e. `signed int`, so, `x = 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111`, after 24 signed right shift, becomes `x = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 1001` which is `-119` in decimal.
If you pass `x` as an `unsigned int`, after 24 unsigned right shift, becomes `x = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 1001` which is equal to `137` in decimal.

This satisfies your required answer:

```
int example(unsigned int x) { 
   return x >> 24;
}
```